# How to add Gutenberg editor on frontend page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a textarea on a public-facing page. I want to add Gutenberg editor to that textarea. I searched the official documentation but couldn't find anything.
Any information will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a WordPress plugin blocks everywhere by Automatic.It will help you to add block support in your every textarea.Just install the plugin and add the below line in your wp-config.php.

```
define( 'BLOCKS_EVERYWHERE_COMMENTS', true );
```